# Does each user get his/her own tty(s)?

Tags: shell, command-line, users, tty

I put a simple echo command in a CLI tty by user1 expecting it to reach user2 who is logged in a separate tty.

```
echo "Hello, world!" >> /dev/tty5
```

I expected user2 to get the echo message but nothing shows up.

Does each user get his/her own "set" of tty[1-7]?

Edit: I suspect this may be a permissions issue. I was actually exploring `cron` jobs and had set a `cron` job to `echo` a "hello world" message every minute from `user1` logged into `tty2` directed to `tty5` where `user2` is logged in but `user2` never got the echoed messages.

Comment: No. See [construct-a-command-by-putting-a-string-into-a-tty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48103/construct-a-command-by-putting-a-string-into-a-tty/48120).

Comment: Have a look at the `write` command. That's more along the line of what you want.

Comment: What shell are you using? Did you get any error message? What is the output of `echo "Hello, world!" >> /dev/tty5; echo $?`?

Comment: @Gilles It's Bash for both users. System is a Centos 6.3 installation.

Answer (score 2):

If `user2` is logged into `tty5`, he is the owner of `/dev/tty5`. If he has messaging enabled, then you can send him a message using `write user2`, but if he doesn't, you're out of luck unless you are `root`. `echo "Hello, world!" >> /dev/tty5` only works if executed by `root` or by `user2`.

Comment: `mesg y` will enable receiving messages and `mesg n` will disable it..