# Output Output of command to command line directly, NOT variable

Tags: bash, command-substitution, line-editor

I am on the bash shell and I want the output of a command to appear directly in the command prompt that appears after the command has executed !

Example of what I envision it, to illustrate my idea:

```
locate create_tables.sql|MAGIC_command
user@localhost:~# /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/create_tables.sql
```

Now, using comman dsubstitution like this

```
sudo $(locate create-tables.sql)
```

works but  **immediately executes** the output, I'd like to be able to edit it before. Is there a way?

Comment: see [this recent question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213799/119298) which is similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Construct a command by putting a string into a tty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48103/80216); see also [How to redirect to stdin of a running bash shell?](http://superuser.com/q/403148/354511)

Answer (score 5):

In Emacs-mode type `sudo $(locate create-tables.sql)`, <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

See `shell-expand-line` in [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Miscellaneous-Commands):

> Expand the line as the shell does. This performs alias and history expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions

Comment: Or ctrl+alt+e if you have your terminal set up nicely.

Answer (score 4):

I generally use the clipboard for this kind of thing

```
$ some_command | cb
$ cb_edit
$ `cb` #or paste it with your paste button/shortcut
```

The magic:

```
 cb() {
  if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    #if somebody's piping in reproduce input and pipe a copy to the clipboard
    tee >(xclip -selection c)
  else
    #otherwise, print the contents of the clipboard
    xclip -selection c -o 
  fi
}
cb_edit() { cb | vipe "$@" | cb; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant solution is to store the output into some tmpfile, edit that file and then run:

```
$ locate create_tables.sql > /tmp/tmpfile
$ vi !$    # last argument of last command
$ bash !$
```