# Dangers of piping to stdin of process in another terminal

Tags: pipe, stdin

Out of malicious curiosity I opened 2 terminals, each running the bash shell. In the first I type :

```
$ echo $$
11458
```

and in the second :

```
$ echo -n "echo this command" >> /proc/11458/fd/0
```

Then this text `echo this command` is indeed piped to the prompt on the first terminal. But on enter in that first terminal, that text is not executed as a command, I just get a new prompt.

In a second attempt, I executed this command in the first terminal:

```
$ read line;echo $line
```

and while the read is waiting for input, I again echo some text to `/proc/11458/fd/0` in the second terminal. That text does appear on the first terminal, but on pressing `<enter>` in the first terminal, the `read` terminates, and the `echo $line` shows that no input was read.

So I still didn't find a way to do harm; all I can do is modify the text on the first terminal, from the second terminal. Screen readers on that first terminal of course, do pick this up. By screen readers I am thinking of mouse selection, or terminal functions like `Save Contents ...`; I tried both.

But if I knew how to also echo, for instance, an end-of-file or other control characters to the first terminal's `stdin`, couldn't I mess up things terribly for processes in the first terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an easy explanation:

If a terminal process writes to the terminal (`stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` all point to the same device/pty), then this output does not become its next input. Obviously.

echo foo

does not have the same effect as typing <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>.

So why would a different process writing to the terminal become another processes terminal input? Doesn't make any sense.

In contrast to a file, with a (pseudo) terminal the data written to and read from it are not related because the data source is something completely different (a keyboard or a program). See `man 7 pty`. A pseudo terminal has a client side which is used by the terminal applications and a master side where the input for the client side is generated.

My terminal emulator is konsole (PID 40818), currently running only one shell/terminal:

```
start cmd:> ll /proc/40818/fd
insgesamt 0
lr-x------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 0 -> 'pipe:[1177680901]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 1 -> 'socket:[89302]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 10 -> /dev/dri/renderD128
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 11 -> /dev/dri/renderD128
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 12 -> /dev/dri/renderD128
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 13 -> /dev/dri/renderD128
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 18 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 19 -> /dev/pts/40
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 2 -> 'socket:[89302]'
l-wx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 21 -> 'pipe:[1177664260]'
lr-x------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 28 -> 'pipe:[1177664264]'
l-wx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 29 -> 'pipe:[1177664264]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 3 -> 'socket:[1177673938]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 4 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 5 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 6 -> 'socket:[1177650969]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 7 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 8 -> 'socket:[1177677086]'
lrwx------ 1 hl hauke 64 27. Nov 15:06 9 -> 'socket:[1177677087]'

ec:0   15:06:36  hl@monster:~
start cmd:> tty
/dev/pts/40
```

You can see, the shell uses `/dev/pts/40` but the terminal emulator writes to  `/dev/ptmx`. Only the file descriptor `18` of the terminal emulator can write to the input of /dev/pts/40. If a different process opens `/dev/ptmx` then it creates a new pseudo terminal to which is written to.

Comment: I cannot directly connect the `/dev/pts/40` and `/dev/ptmx`  you mention, to your stdin and stdout; are the latter still filedescriptors 0 and 1?  But the first part of your answer makes sense to me. Until 30 years ago I programmed low-level MS-DOS programs, and I remember something about the difference between hooking to the keyboard interrupt, and reading from the keyboard buffer. And I recollect that in C you had to be consistent about using either `putc` and it's relatives, or `putchar`. So I accept your answer as sufficient to take away my fears.

Comment: Yes, `stdin` and `stdout` are still 0 and 1. I have no problem connecting to them (except for the fact that two shells reading from the same pty simultaneously leads to strange results). I execute `tty` in a different terminal and get `/dev/pts/11`. Then I run (elsewhere): `bash -c 'echo $$; exec 0</dev/pts/11;cat'`

Answer (score 5):

Part 1 - does this answer your question? [Writing to stdin of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process)

Part 2 - you can write to (and read from) a terminal belonging to any process that you own. But standard UNIX permissions will prevent you writing to (or reading from) any device that's associated with a different user login.

```
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/0
lrwx------ 1 roaima roaima 64 Nov 27 13:19 /proc/7859/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/0

ls -lL /proc/$$/fd/0
crw--w---- 1 roaima tty 136, 0 Nov 27 13:24 /proc/7859/fd/0
```

I can write to this device:

```
( tput smso; echo 'surprise!' ) >/dev/pts/0
```

Comment: On your Part 1, I actually did read that question before daring mine. I looked up the TIOCSTI you commented on there, and it hightened my fear, because _Simulate terminal input_ is exactly what seems dangerous to me.  _Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'_ too had in his anser the possibility _If /proc/PID/fd/0 is a pipe, then writing to it appends the data to the pipe's buffer. In that case, the process that's reading from the pipe will read the data._ And then in the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385782/376817) the stdX are linked to `/dev/pty#`, mine to `/dev/pts/#`.

Comment: On your Part 2. What you are saying, is that when I mess up, it's my own authorized mess. Thanks for the reassurance. The problem is that I am also the root of my private personal computer, and a linux newbie.

Comment: Db-inf generally it's better not to run day to day as root. Very little will stop you doing so, because it's your mschine, but it's better to do stuff as a normal user for as much of the time as possible

Comment: Don't worry. Also is not a synonym of always.